# Tikz. Creating a perpendicular line to an arbitrary line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Does anybody have an idea how to generate perpendicular lines to an arbitrary line in Tikz? 
As you can see, in the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [black, thick,fill=white] (0.0,0.0) circle [radius=0.75];
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (cos{45}*0.75,sin{45}*0.75);
\node at (0.1,0.4) {{ ${r}$}};
\draw [->,thick] (-3,0) -- (-1.75,0);
\draw  [thick] (-1.75,0) -- (-0.5,0.0);
\draw  [thick,dashed] (-0.75,0) -- (0,0);
\draw  [thick,dashed] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.75,0.0);
\draw  [->,thick] (0.5,0.0) -- (1.75,0.0);
\draw  [thick, dashed] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.0,0.75);
\draw  [->,thick] (0.0,0.4) -- (0.0,2);
\node at (1.9,0.0) {{\large $z$}};
\node at (0.0,2.1) {{\large $y$}};
\draw  [thick] (-2.3,-0.25) -- (-2.3,0.25);
\draw  [thick] (-2.2,-0.25) -- (-2.2,0.25);
\path 
    (1,0) coordinate (a)
    -- (0,0) coordinate (O)
    -- (1,1) coordinate (b)
  pic["$\theta$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.35,angle radius=0.4cm] {angle=a--O--b};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I've had no trouble in creating perpendicular lines to the  $x$-axis. I'm now trying to do something similar to the line passing through the origin of the following diagram

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,thick] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right, at end] {\large$x$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,3.5)--(0,-3.5)node[right, at end] {\large$y$};;
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) -- (3,2);
\path 
    (0,3.5) coordinate (a)
    -- (0,0) coordinate (O)
    -- (3,2) coordinate (b)
  pic["$\theta_1$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=b--O--a};
\draw [thick] (3,-2)--(-3,2);
\path 
    (0,3.5) coordinate (e)
    -- (0,0) coordinate (O)
    -- (-3,2) coordinate (f)
  pic["$\theta_1$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=e--O--f};
\draw[->,very thick] (-3,-2)--(-1.5,-1);
\node at (-1.5,-1.3) {{$\mathbf{l}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

Comment: You always can edit your own posts. So you should rather do this, than posting missing stuff as a comment.

Comment: Please always post complete minimal examples which can be compiled. This one can't. And it doesn't need `tikz-3dplot`, I don't think. But it does need a class and the `document` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading the `calc` library, you can draw perpendicular lines. I made the line dashed for the example, so you see it better.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw [->,thick] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right, at end] {\large$x$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,3.5) coordinate (topy) --(0,-3.5)node[right, at end] {\large$y$};;
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) -- (3,2) coordinate (line1);
\path 
    (topy)
    -- (O)
    -- (line1)
  pic["$\theta_1$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=line1--O--topy};
\draw [thick, dashed] ($(O)!3.5cm!90:(line1)$) coordinate (f) -- ($(O)!3.5cm!-90:(line1)$);
\path 
    (topy)
    -- (O)
    -- (f) 
  pic["$\theta_1$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=topy--O--f};
\draw[->,very thick] (-3,-2)--(-1.5,-1);
\node at (-1.5,-1.3) {{$\mathbf{l}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: how you know which like to be orthogonal to an arbitrary other? to me this question is ambiguous/unclear ...

Comment: @Zarko Because in the question he said: "I've had no trouble in creating perpendicular lines to the $x$-axis. I'm now trying to do something similar to the line passing through the origin of the following diagram". The first sentence refers to the axis lines, the second one to the oblique line. Besides, it's the only line in the picture without a perpendicular line. I assumed the second line was his attempt to draw it.

Comment: Alenanno is correct, it would have been unusual for me to refer to the coordinate axes as a line passing through the origin after I had just talked about the coordinate axis case.

Comment: well, than i need repair my crystal ball ... it need serious service :-) .  by the way, now the angles $\theta_1$ and complementary one aren't anymore equal.

Comment: If you can't repair your crystal ball you could just use your common sense. And I have noticed, thanks:)